# Odd and even number separator

Tags: python

I had been given this problem to write a code which will get a line of numbers on the input and will separate them into odd and even.

> You get a line with natural numbers on the input. Sort them and write out the odd ones separately, the even ones separately

This is where had I gone so far, but I have mainly I think problem with separating and including the with the numbers from the input.

**Input: 8 11 4 3 7 2 6 13 5 12**

**even: 6 4 2 6 12**

**odd: 11 3 7 13 5**

```
a=[]
for i in range(1,100):
    b=int(input().split())
    a.append(b)
even=[]
odd=[]
for j in a:
    if(j%2==0):
        even.append(j)
    else:
        odd.append(j)
print("The even list:",even)
print("The odd list:",odd)
```

Comment: What is your question? What happens when you run this code? What do you want it to do instead? Please [edit] your question to include more details.

Comment: "You get a line with natural numbers on the input. Sort them and write out the odd ones separately, the even ones separately."   And my approach was to include the input to the list and then separate the numbers one by one depending if they're odd or even into separate lists and then print them

Comment: I suspect your code throws an error at `input().split()` cannot be parsed into one number?

Comment: @Proxim17y You should [edit] your question instead of posting comments.

Comment: Yes it will do i've checked that

Comment: @Proxim17y Your overall approach is correct. But what is the actual problem you encountered? If you get an error, [edit] the question to include it. Better yet, google the error message to find the answer more quickly.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, but I can't think of any other way to split the numbers on the input, and If I don't include the .split(), I still get error

Comment: I don't understand the for loop from 1 to 100 to get the input.  I assume the input is coming as a single line of space separated numbers, and not up to 100 separate inputs with no STOP input.  you probably just want `b=input()` `a = [int(x) for x in b.split()]`

Comment: @Proxim17y The `.split()` is correct. However, when you apply `int()` to the result, you are attempting to convert **the entire list** into a single number. This doesn't make sense. The problem is that you are trying to do too many things all at one time. Instead, break it down into smaller steps. For example, just get the input `user_input = input()`.  Then split it `split_input = user_input.split()`. Then convert the list of input strings into a list of numbers. Continue in this way until you finish the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to separate the odds and evens into separate lists looks okay, but your code to create the list from input in the first place looks wrong. You're trying to convert a list generated by `input().split()` into an int.

Instead use a list comprehension to make each element of that list into an int.

```
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Comment: You're right - there's more than one error in this piece of code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def separator(lst):

    odd = []
    even = []

    for i in lst:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            even.append(i)
        else:
            odd.append(i)

    return odd, even
```

Answer (score 0):

Unclear why you need a loop to build any lists.

Just parse the input

```
a = map(int, input().split())
```

Then the rest of the code over `a` to build two lists is fine

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why are you using a for loop? Secondly, you split the input into a list and pass it into the int function, which won't work. You need to split the list, and convert each element into an int seperately. The rest is fine.

Working code:

```py
lst = [int(num) for num in input("Enter space seperated numbers: ").split()]
even = []
odd = []

for num in lst:
  if num % 2 == 0:
    even.append(num)
  else:
    odd.append(num)

print(f"The even numbers are: {even}.")
print(f"The odd numbers are: {odd}.")
```